# Prometheus to count unique label value

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, promql, grafana-variable

I am  looking for a way to count the unique label values and show each unique label count for each customer name. Here are my metrics. I need to get the count as apple=1, orange=1.

```
 customer_alerts(alertname="a", customername="apple")
 customer_alerts(alertname="b", customername="orange")
 customer_alerts(alertname="a", customername="apple")
```

I tried the below query and it is showing the total count as 2, but i would like to show the count map to each customer name. How can I do that?

`Example: apple=1, orange=1`

`count(count by (alertname)(customer_alerts[24h])))`

Please note I am using grafana to create the dashboard.